# Navigate to a directory from a favorites list

Tags: bash, cd-command

Like everyone, I use the `cd` builtin command to navigate my directory-structure. Tab-completion comes in handy. Sometimes I use `pushd` and `popd` to jump between directories.

Some of those directories I use a lot. Is there a way to store them as a favorite, and then jump to that favorite by name?

I could easily shell-script this, and actually already did. But I want to know if there is a builtin, command or installable script for this.

I use bash 3.2 on macOS, but also bash 4.4 on Debian.

Answer (score 4):

man bash:

```
   CDPATH The  search  path for the cd command.  This is a colon-separated
          list of directories in which the  shell  looks  for  destination
          directories  specified  by  the  cd  command.  A sample value is
          ".:~:/usr".
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that one. Is there also a way to add these to auto complete (TAB)?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a favorites list, but a "parent of favorites" list: you can set the `CDPATH` bash shell variable to a list of directories you wish the shell to search when executing `cd ...`.

For example, if you had directories

```
/home/doekman/work/projects/alpha
/home/doekman/work/projects/beta
/home/doekman/work/projects/gamma
```

Then, by setting `CDPATH` to `~/work/projects`, you could switch to one of the subdirectories of `projects` with, *e.g.*

```
cd beta
```